# Flask WTForms IntegerField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

wtforms.IntegerField.data not passed to html template on a post method but on a get method it is.

Replacing the IntegerField with StringField in code below does pass the data to the html template. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    number = IntegerField('Number')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    form = TestForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form.number.data = 100
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form.number.data = 200
    return render_template('number.html', form=form)
```

Comment: try changing the title to a more descriptive one to guide other members

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same issue. A workaround I found is to set the value in the template. This is certainly not optimal, but it works for now.

```
{% if form.number.data %}
{{ form.number(value=form.number.data) }}
{% else %}
{{ form.number() }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tripped up on a similar issue. Your solution works. Thank you Pox and Wimpie for posting this